# Ajuda para abortar requisição jQuery.ajax, jQuery.post

Tags: jquery

Uso uma página em php para monitorar novas inserções no banco de dados por 30s e até aqui tudo funciona bem, o problema é que não consigo sair imediatamente da página principal, pois ela fica aguardando a resposta da solicitação e o final do loop no php.

Pelo que pesquisei devo usar o .abort(); para abortar a requisição, mas estou tendo dificuldades em seu uso, pois ele não parece funcionar dentro da função fail(), que é chamada quando tento mudar de página sem a resposta da requisição.

Basicamente eu faço a chamada na página principal:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>monitoramento('parametros');</script>
```

Envio a solicitação via Jquery.ajax (já tentei com Jquery.post também) para a página em php que vai fazer o monitoramento no DB:

```html
function monitoramento(parametros){
    var longp = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "monitoramento-tags.php",
        data: { "parametro":parametros },
        //dataType: "dataType",
        success: function (resposta) {
            $("#usuarios").html(resposta);
        }
    });

    // Esse funciona
    //longp.abort();


    longp.fail(function(){
        alert('FECHAR')
        // Esse não funciona
        longp.abort();
    });
}
```

E a página em php, que resumidamente monitora novos registros por 30s:

```php
...
for($x=0; $x<30;$x++){

   // Realiza consulta no DB

   // Espera 1s antes da próxima consulta
   sleep(1);
}
...
```

Resumindo: Quero sair da página principal e navegar pelo site, porém, a solicitação feita usando jQuery.ajax fica aguardando resposta da página php, o que pode demorar até 30s para acontecer, ou seja, eu clico em um link e tenho que ficar esperando ao invés de abortar a solicitação e mudar imediatamente de página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar acabei encontrando a solução, na verdade não tem nada haver com o jQuery.ajax ou jQuery.post e sim com a página php, pois nela utilizo uma sessão que acaba bloqueando a finalização.

A solução é um tanto quanto simples, embora a identificação do problema nem tanto. Enfim, basta usar session_write_close() após o uso da sessão, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```php
// Abro a sessão
session_start();
...
// Manipulo a sessão, se necessário
...
// Finalizo o bloqueio e a manipulação da sessão
session_write_close();
...
// Continuo com o restante do código
...
```

Agradecimento / Referência / Fonte: [imasters Artigos](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/php-session-locking-como-evitar-bloqueio-de-sessoes-nas-solicitacoes-php)